# What do you mean by left to right associativity in this case?

Tags: c++, operators, ostream, associativity

I was reading about the << operator in c++ from C++ Primer.
In it, there are some lines written about << operator

> cout << "Some string" evaluates to a left hand ostream operator that is the result of the expression is cout object itself.(We say that operator associates left to right) .

It would be great it someone explains what is the meaning of the above mentioned lines.

Comment: It means it works the oppsite way of assignment operator which starts evaluating from the right as in `x = y = z = 5;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left to right associativity means that the expression is implicitly parenthesized like this:

```
(((cout << "foo") << "bar") << "baz")
```

In other words, the leftmost operation comes first.

By contrast, assignment is right-associative in most languages:

```
a = b = c + 5;
```

assigns `c + 5` to both "a" and "b" because the assignment operator works from right-to-left.

Answer (score 4):

It means that

```
cout << a << b
```

is the same as

```
(cout << a) << b
```

not

```
cout << (a << b)
```

To clarify: the `cout << a` part outputs a, then returns cout, so the result of `(cout << a)` can be used as the left side to `<< b`. Left-associativity just means if brackets could make the expression mean something else, assume brackets are set from left to right.